# dotnet-sonarscanner - fails on post-processing - "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

trying to get the sonar scanner running from the command line at the moment with just `msbuild.exe solution.sln /rebuild` it's currently failing on the post-processing step and i can't seem to get beyond that

my java path is set in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`. I tried updating my path to a location that didn't have any spaces in it but no luck.

I also tried using dotnet sonar scanner and msbuild sonar scanner. both with the same result

These are the steps i'm executing:

```
dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"key" /d:sonar.host.url="https://my_company_sonarqube.com" /d:sonar.login="token" /d:sonar.verbose=true

MSBuild.exe solution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Platform="Any CPU"

dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="token"
```

Everything seems to work fine until i get to the post-processing step:

```
Executing file C:\Users\userid\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-sonarscanner\4.7.1\dotnet-sonarscanner\4.7.1\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any\sonar-scanner-4.1.0.1829\bin\sonar-scanner.bat
  Args: -Dsonar.scanAllFiles=true -Dproject.settings=C:\Users\userid\Documents\project_path\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties --embedded --debug <sensitive data removed>
  Working directory: C:\Users\userid\Documents\project_path
  Timeout (ms):-1
  Process id: 38116
Error: Could not find or load main class 
Process returned exit code 1
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
19:53:44.155  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Using the following JDK

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so i'm not sure why i was getting the main class error. I re-ran everything using the sonarscanner batch script and then with a stripped down java call from the batch script and it seems like my problem was not having my ssl certificates for the sonarqube server.

Starting over and setting SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS seemed to do the trick.

`set SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS =  "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\path\to\trustStore"`